# Swifty way of naming a boolean property

Tags: swift

1.

According to the [swift API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), a boolean property should read as assertions

> Uses of Boolean methods and properties should read as assertions about

> the receiver when the use is nonmutating,
>   e.g. x.isEmpty, line1.intersects(line2).

2.

I would like to make a computed property of which type is Boolean to the existing data type.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
struct State {
    var authorID: String
    var myID: String
    var `XXX`: Bool {
        return myID == authorID
    }
}
```

I want the property `XXX` to stand for whether I am author or not.

I firstly came up with the names like `authorIsMe`, `iAmAuthor`, `isAuthorMe`, etc. but realized that it didn’t read as assertions about the receiver.

So, what name do you think fit best for `XXX`? Any idea will be appreciated.

Thank you

(Please do not consider inlining the expression `myID == authorID` because in the original code, it is not short as above so I need the computed property)

Comment: What is about `isStateAuthor`?

Comment: You can use isAuthor

Comment: What is `State` supposed to represent?

Comment: Thank you all. `State` represents a general state from a redux-like framework  (e.g https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift).

Answer (score 0):

`amITheAuthor` is the best property name according to me as it will clearly throw the answer & its means of use , its a suggestion you can use this as well.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your opinion!